# meaning of "ghetto kids"

Tags: meaning, nuance

I'm going to translate the following sentence into a language in which there may not be an exact equivalent for the word 'ghetto'.

> He taught ghetto kids in New York's public school system.

(Update: In this sentence, the pronoun 'he' refers to [Henry Spira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Spira), a benevolent leftist activist. The text highly praises him. And, by the way, the author is the Australian philosopher [Peter Singer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Singer).)

Concise Oxford English Dictionary defines 'ghetto' as

> 1) a part of a city, especially a slum area, occupied by a minority group.
>
> 2) [historical] the Jewish quarter in a city.

Now, I'd like to know what adjectives and concepts the phrase *"ghetto kids of New York"*  brings to the mind of a native English speaker most strongly at this moment in time.

Comment: Since New-York's Jewish population was never concentrated in ghetto's and the slum area of New York city is called ghetto, I think you should find a word which describes a word which describes 1 in your target language. Take a look at the United State section in the [wikipedia entery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghetto#United_States)

Comment: You might try a term meaning "underprivileged".  This word is often used as a less prejudicial  term for occupants of a "ghetto".

Comment: As phrased, this question is highly opinion-based, in that many different "adjectives and concepts" could come to the mind of answerers. For example, I think of *institutional racism* and *economic segregation*, whereas someone else might think in terms of racial or class-based stereotypes. If you could rephrase the question to focus on register rather than reader bias, you might get better-researched answers.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin  - yes -  I would think of "systematically oppressed kids with horizons limmited by the world they live in"  AND some of the stereotypes that might walk hand in hand, at least in terms of posturing and style (less so the truly derogatory stereotypes of less admirable traits) Some one, some the other, some both - very opinion based

Comment: Is this a translation from your native language (if so, please give that), or is it an exercise in writing English as a foreign language. Note that the Concise OED entry you gave lists  the Jewish associated meaning of ghetto as 'historical', meaning it is not used that way any more for current areas where lots of Jewish people live. Historically it refers to areas like the [Warsaw Ghetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Ghetto) (created during WWII) or its namesake [the Venetian Ghetto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venetian_Ghetto). The word is not used like that anymore.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin, thanks for your comment. I've added a small update to the question with the hope that it somewhat clarifies the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Mitch, thanks for your comment. I'm translating the whole text from English into my native language, which is Persian. I didn't like to mention it. :)

Comment: @Arham Oh... so you're going the other direction, away from English. Then that first definition is good enough. The word has many different connotations, but those depend a lot on the US urban context and race relations which probably don't have an exact parallel there. But any word or expression that connotes 'slum' and identifiably minority (ethnic, race) would fit in a translation.

Comment: Doesn't Persian have a word for slum? A ghetto is a slum. ghettos kids=slum kids. https://en.radiofarda.com/a/iran-population-sliding-into-more-poverty/28661812.html

Comment: @Lambie, Persian has a word for slum, as English has for جنایت. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BXtgq0Nhsc

Comment: Ok,so you have your answer. And can now translate the phrase: slum kids.

Answer (score 2):

"Ghetto kids" is an American expression that, in this context, refers to less-advantaged, generally poor-behaved children who are difficult to manage in a classroom.  It is also dated. This was a very common expression in the 70's, but not so much now from my personal experience.

A good reference for this the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ghetto), definition 2.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92560/discussion-on-answer-by-karlomanio-meaning-of-ghetto-kids).